# Apache2 SSL certificate file issue

Tags: apache, apache2

I am new to https ( HTTP using SSL). I have managed to generate a self signed certificate file and have added the following lines to the apache conf file:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/file/myfile.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key/file/myfile.key
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

The issue I am having is that when I try to restart my server I get the following error and am confused why it is not able to read it:

```
Starting web server apache2
Syntax error on line 1 of /path/to/cert/file/myfile.crt:
Invalid command 'MIIDtTCCAx6gAwIBAgIJAOnu0fcwBt1BMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGZMQswCQYD', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
   ...fail!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it tries to interpret the certificate file as a script. Is the crt file executable?

Answer (score -1):

man this is outdated.. well i guess you should start from the beginning with a good howto. just google  apache2 ssl howto.

propably apache has no ssl module loaded.
on debian you could try apache2ctl -M to list all loaded modules.